# Custom validation using make:request returns controller not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Using `php artisan make:request StoreUserData` I've create my rules to the request:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreUserData extends FormRequest {
    public function rules(){
        return [
            'name'=>'required|integer',
            'surname'=>'required|max:255|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use it in controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserDataController extends Controller {
    public function store(StoreUserData $request){
        return 'valid';
    }
}
```

Here the error I get: **Class App\Http\Controllers\StoreUserData does not exist**.

PS. Is not a problem of routing.
I'm following this documentation since I'm using Laravel 5.6 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Just tried @J.Doe still not working...

Comment: you forget to import `StoreUserData`, try adding `use App\Http\Requests\StoreUserData` in your controller

Comment: Yep @rkj thanks a lot!!! I'm so tired... Feel free to post it as answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: glad, it works for you. added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you use `StoreUserData` in controller method then you have to import that class otherwise it will assume the class is in `App\Http\Controllers` namespace and thats why it throw **Class App\Http\Controllers\StoreUserData does not exist**.

just add the below import at top of your controller class

```
use App\Http\Requests\StoreUserData
```